# difference b/w const int func(); and int func() const;

Tags: c++, function, constants

I know when we use

```
 int func() const;
```

then we cannot modify anything in the function except for mutable variable.
But when i used

```
const int func();
```

It is allowing me to modify any thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const int func();
```

is function that returns `const int` and

```
int func() const;
```

is `const` function, i.e. function that doesn't modify the state of object, upon which it has been called.

Comment: As a side note hardly related to the question, but still worth mentioning, returning a `const` value is frowned upon now that we have move semantics (because it inhibits moving). Not to be confused with returning a `const` reference, which has very different semantics than returning by (`const`) value.